# Why does't the onCreate() in MySQLiteHelper(extends SQLiteOpenHelper)execute?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have codes whit sq-lite,but there are some errors.I've a worked several days,but it doesn't work.
I write the MySQLiteHelper class(extends SQLiteOpenHelper).

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String CLASSIFICATION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classification(classification_id Integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,classify VARCHAR)";
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account(account_id Integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,username VARCHAR,password VARCHAR,classification_id Integer REFERENCES classification(classification_id))";
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context,name,factory,version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CLASSIFICATION);
        db.execSQL(ACCOUNT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

I write the MySQLiteDatabase class.

```
public class MySQLiteDatabase  {
    private static MySQLiteDatabase instance;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private MySQLiteDatabase(Context context){
        MySQLiteHelper helper = new MySQLiteHelper(context,"test.db",null,1);
        sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO classification(classification_id,classify) VALUES(1,'QQ')");
    }
    public static MySQLiteDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if(null == instance){
            instance = new MySQLiteDatabase(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But I write the code in the onCreate() in SampleActivity.

```
MySQLiteDatabase my = MySQLiteDatabase.getInstance(SampleActivity.this);
```

### the onCreate() in MySQLiteHelper does't execute?

In the other way,I write the follow code in the onCreate() in Sample Activity.The onCreate() in MySQLiteHelper execute.

```
 MySQLiteHelper helper = new MySQLiteHelper(context,"test.db",null,1);
```

I have try my best to solve it,but I can't.Please help me.

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: prolly because it is called only once (if database not exists) ...

Comment: if you have changed the tables since then, you need to increase the version count. And use `getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: the error is nullpointerexception

Comment: The stack trace contains more information than that. If you keep it a secret, nobody can help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I have written all codes.

Answer (score 0):

Database helper `onCreate()` is only called by the framework when

- you're calling `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`, and
- the database file didn't exist.

Chances are the database file already exists. Unisntall your app or clear its data to get rid of it.

Comment: I think my code meet the requirement,but it does't work.

Comment: I have written getWritableDatabase() in MySQLiteDatabase'getIstance() why the onCreate() doesn't execute?